# AngularJS view can't update when model changes

Tags: angularjs

This is config file `config.js`:

```
.state ('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'views/common.html'
})
.state ('home.mypage', {
    url: '/mypage',
    templateUrl: 'views/mypage.html'
})
```

Here is `common.html`:

```
<header id="header" data-ng-include src="'views/template/header.html'"></header>
<section id="main">
    <aside id="leftside" data-ng-include src="'views/template/leftside.html'"></aside>
    <aside id="rightside" data-ng-include src="'views/template/rightside.html'" data-ng-controller="mypageCtrl"></aside>
    <section id="content" class="page-view" data-ui-view></section>
</section> 
<footer id="footer" data-ng-include src="'views/template/footer.html'"></footer>
```

**rightside.html** contains inputs and search button for api calls and **mypage.html** contains something like that `<div class="container ng-scope" data-ng-controller="mypageCtrl">`.

When ajax success:

```
function (data) {
    $scope.results = data.results;
    $scope.pagination = data._meta.pagination;
}
```

When I request **mypage** and first appears result is ok even when clicking on pager. But when I click search button in **rightside.html**, view(mypage.html) is not update even ajax response have result.

What am I wrong? How can I update view when model have changes?

**EDIT:**
This is `mypageController.js`

```
materialAdmin
    .controller('mypageCtrl', function($location, $scope, mypageService) {
        $scope.search = function(conditions) {
            return (mypageService.search(conditions).then(
                function (data) {
                    $scope.results = data.results;
                    $scope.pagination = data._meta.pagination;
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            ) );
        };
        $scope.search($scope.conditions); // Initial search when request page
})
```

and `mypageService.js`

```
materialAdmin.service("mypageService", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        search: search
        // and more functions
    };

    function search(conditions) {
        return ( $http.post(
            BASE_URL + "/search", conditions).then(
            handleSuccess,
            function (response) {
                handleError(response, $q)
            }
        ) );
    }
}]);
```

Comment: What are you using `$http` or `$.ajax`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe in your question, the problem seems to be that you have two instances of the same controller. One is created here

```
    <aside id="rightside" data-ng-include src="'views/template/rightside.html'" data-ng-controller="mypageCtrl"></aside>
```

The other is created on the **mypage.html** file.

You are seeing the correct behavior when you load because the controller on mypage.html is working and so the information is getting pulled and displayed.

But when you click on the button in **rightside** the controller (or more acurately the scope) that is getting updated is the one on rightside (which has no data display) so you still see the data in mypage.html

The solution to your problem in this case is rather simple. Just delete both controllers declarations and redeclare your controller in the section element on the common page. You will get the correct behavior.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you found it usefult, could you give the answer an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function (data) {
    $scope.results = data.results;
    $scope.pagination = data._meta.pagination;
    updateScope();
}

function updateScope(){
    if(!$scope.$$phase){
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

This makes sure the $scope apply cycle runs after the AJAX call is completed, so that the update is reflected in the DOM.

Comment: `if` condition is always `false` and still view was not changes.

Comment: Yes thats not to be executed simply. It is just a fallback case when the angular update cycle doesn't run.With this it is always fullproof, however Angular handles it, it will be updated in the view as well. If it still doesn't work, can you please expose a little more of the code. That would be a lot helpful for both of us.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your search method in `mypageService` is not returning a promise, but that is what you expect in your controller `mypageCtrl`. Therefore, the `successcallback` is actually not executed. I would suggest changing this method to return a promise like this:

```
function search(conditions) {
    return $http.post(BASE_URL + "/search", conditions);
}
```